# Buffering data from sockets?

Tags: c, buffer, sockets

I am trying to make a simple HTTP server that would be able to parse client requests and send responses back.

Now I have a problem. I have to read and handle one line at a time in the request, and I don't know if I should:

- read one byte at a time, or
- read chunks of *N* bytes at a time, put them in a buffer, and then handle the bytes one by one, before reading a new chunk of bytes.

What would be the best option, **and why**?

Also, are there some alternative solutions to this? Like a function that would read a line at a time from the socket or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that I would go with reading a single byte at a time. Unfortunately its one of those cases where there are pros and cons for both cases.

For the use of a buffer is the fact that the implementation can be more efficient from the perspective of the network IO. Against the use of a buffer, I think that the code will be inherently more complex than the single byte version. So its an efficiency vs complexity trade off. The good news is that you can implement the simple solution first, profile the result and "upgrage" to a buffered approach if testing shows it to be worthwhile.

Also, just to note, as a *thought experiment* I wrote some pseudo code for a loop that does buffer based reads of http packets, included below. The complexity to implement a buffered read doesn't seem to bad. Note however that I haven't given much consideration to error handling, or tested if this will work at all. However, it  should avoid excessive "double handling" of data, which is important since that would reduce the efficiency gains which were the purpose of this approach.

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 1024

nextHttpBytesRead = 0;
nextHttp = NULL;
while (1)
{
  size_t httpBytesRead = nextHttpBytesRead;
  size_t thisHttpSize;
  char *http = nextHttp;
  char *temp;
  char *httpTerminator;

  do
  {
    temp = realloc(httpBytesRead + CHUNK_SIZE);
    if (NULL == temp)
      ...
    http = temp;

    httpBytesRead += read(httpSocket, http + httpBytesRead, CHUNK_SIZE);
    httpTerminator = strstr(http, "\r\n\r\n");
  }while (NULL == httpTerminator)

  thisHttpSize = ((int)httpTerminator - (int)http + 4; // Include terminator
  nextHttpBytesRead = httpBytesRead - thisHttpSize;

  // Adding CHUNK_SIZE here means that the first realloc won't have to do any work
  nextHttp = malloc(nextHttpBytesRead + CHUNK_SIZE);
  memcpy(nextHttp,  http + thisHttpSize, nextHttpSize);

  http[thisHttpSize] = '\0';
  processHttp(http);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Single byte at a time is going to kill performance.  Consider a circular buffer of decent size.

Read chunks of whatever size is free in the buffer.  Most of the time you will get short reads.  Check for the end of the http command in the read bytes.  Process complete commands and next byte becomes head of buffer.  If buffer becomes full, copy it off to a backup buffer, use a second circular buffer, report an error or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Can you explain me the concept "circular buffer" please?

Comment: @Math - it is basically an array that wraps the end around to the beginning.  Pointers keep track of the head & tail & current position, etc.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Answer (score 1):

TCP data stream is coming in at one IP packet at a time, which can be up to 1,500 or so bytes depending on the IP layer configuration.  In Linux this is going to be wait in one SKB waiting for the application layer to read off the queue.  If you read one byte at a time you suffer the overhead of context switches between the application and kernel for simply copying one byte from one structure to another.  The optimum solution is to use non-blocking IO to read the content of one SKB at a time and so minimize the switches.

If you are after optimum bandwidth you could read off longer size of bytes in order to further reduce the context switches at the expensive of latency as more time will be spent out of the application copying memory.  But this only applies to extremes and such code changes should be implemented when required.

If you examine the multitude of existing HTTP technologies you can find alternative approaches such as using multiple threads and blocking sockets, pushing more work back into the kernel to reduce the overhead of switching into the application and back.

I have implemented a HTTP server library very similar to **torak**'s pseudo code here,  http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/http.c  The biggest speed improvements for this implementation came from making everything asynchronous so nothing ever blocks.

Answer (score 1):

[Indy](http://www.indyproject.org), for example, takes the buffered approach.  When the code asks Indy to read a line, it first checks its current buffer to see if a line break is present.  If not, the network is read in chunks and appended to the buffer until the line break appears.  Once it does, just the data up to the line break is removed from the buffer and returned to the app, leaving any remaining data in the buffer for the next reading operation.  This makes for a good balance between a simple application-level API (ReadLine, ReadStream, etc), while providing for efficient network I/O (read everything that is currently available in the socket, buffer it, and ack it so the sender is not waiting too long - fewer network-level reads are needed this way).

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading one byte at a time (though noting that lines end with cr/lf in HTTP) because it's simple. If that's not sufficient, do more complex things.

Comment: But be prepared to also handle single cr and single lf as end of line, since there are many client & server out there that are not really HTTP compliants...

Answer (score 0):

Read a byte array buffer at a time. Reading single characters will be dog slow because of the multiple context switches between user and kernel mode (depending on the libc actually).

If you read buffers, you need to be prepared that the buffer could eighter be not filled completely (watch the length return), that the buffer does not contain enough bytes to line end or that the buffer contains more than one line.

It is a common pattern in network applications how to map your line or fixed-size block requests to that variable steam of buffers (and often implemented wrong, for example a 0 byte length answer is possible). Higher languages will hide you from this complexity.